# How to put forest in 2 columns page?

Tags: forest, trees

I have a 2-column article in which I would like to put a forest in 2 column instead of one, and at the top of page.

Here is the code:

```
\newcommand{\CLASSINPUTbottomtextmargin}{25.4mm}
\newcommand{\CLASSINPUTtoptextmargin}{19.1mm}
\newcommand{\CLASSINPUToutersidemargin}{15.8mm}
\newcommand{\CLASSINPUTinnersidemargin}{17mm}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{-5pt}
\documentclass[letterpaper,conference]{IEEEtran}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array,multirow,makecell}
\usepackage{forest}

\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\setcellgapes{1pt}
\makegapedcells
\newenvironment{multicases}[1]
{\let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
\left\lbrace\def\arraystretch{1.2}%
\array{@{}l*{#1}{@{\quad}l}@{}}}
{\endarray\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace}

\title{The principal title: hello !}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.this is just a text.


\begin{figure*}[!b]
\centering
\scalebox{.9}{

    \begin{forest}
for tree={rectangle,draw, l sep=20pt}
    [This is the root node, black 
        [This is the first level  
          [This is the second level
            [This is the third level, edge label={node[midway,right] {hi !!}}
            ]
            [This is the third level]
            [This is the third level]
          ]
        ]
        [This is the first level
            [This is the second level]
            [This is the second level
                [This is the second level, edge label={node[midway,left] {hi}}
                    [This is the second level, edge label={node[midway,left] {hello !!}}
                    ]
                ]
                [This is the third level]
                [This is the third level]
             ] 
        ] 
    ]
    \end{forest}
            }

\caption{My figure}
\end{figure*}


\end{document}
```

Thanks for your answers, however the tree is not well placed at the bottom of the page, and there is a part that goes out of the border.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Why not nest it in a `figure*`  environment? It will go at the top of the following page.

Comment: @Bernard, Thank you, I try it but there is a part that goes out of the page. So, how it could be scaled down to fit into the page ?

Comment: You have the `\scalebox` command from the `graphicx`  package.

Comment: @Bernard, thank you again, the issue is solved

Comment: Pleaseextend your code fragment to complete small document, which we can compile as it is. If your tree is to wide, you have more possibilities: make node narrower (with break node's text into more lines),  rotate image in landscape orientation or ...

Comment: @Lee, if the problem is solved, please show us solution. My testsshows, that it spill out of page significantly.

Comment: @Zarko, the code was edited, you can see the full version. thanks

Answer (score 2):

- Unfortunately, you provide only code fragment, so we not know anything about layout of the your document.
- I would not use `\scalebox`, It will reduce font size to to an illegible size
- As reasonable solution is redesign tree's node, i.e. enble break nodes' texts to two or more lines. For example:

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{forest}
%---------- Shows page layout. Doesn't use it in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
\centering
    \begin{forest}
for tree={
    draw, 
    text width=22mm, text centered, % <--- new
    l sep=9mm,
    s sep=1mm}
    [This is the root node, black
        [This is the first level
          [This is the second level
            [This is the third level, edge label={node[midway,left] {hi !!}}
            ]
            [This is the third level]
            [This is the third level]
          ]
        ]
        [This is the first level
            [This is the second level]
            [This is the second level
                [This is the third level, edge label={node[midway,left] {hi}}
                    [This is the fourth level, edge label={node[midway,left] {hello !!}}
                    ]
                ]
                [This is the third level]
                [This is the third level]
             ]
        ]
    ]
\end{forest}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```